# Recommended MySQL monitoring tool

Tags: mysql, performance, monitoring, operating-system

I am looking for a good all-in-one monitoring tool for a single MySQL server and underlying Linux OS.  I need something that gives me a quick graphical view of what is going on right now and that alerts me to issues / potential issues.  If it can also give recommendations, even better.  I need to be able to see historical data and trends, and preferably have an easy way to see "what changed??"  This data should preferably include relevant OS metrics, such as CPU, iops, RAM utilization, etc.

I don't have a DBA, so MySQL administration is just one of 15 different hats I am wearing in our small IT department.   I plan to purchase a commercial support contract from Percona or MySQL, but I still need a decent monitoring tool (to be my "virtual DBA", if you will).

Some candidates I have come across are: MonYog, Hyperic HQ, DBTuna & Jet Profiler.  I would be interested in knowing about these tools and others from people who have used them in real-world scenarios in detecting & debugging issues, etc.

The platform for the monitoring tool can be either Windows or Linux, it does not matter much.

Input / advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to metrics IMHO you can't get better than the MySQL Cacti templates found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/). That doesn't really help you in regards to monitoring/alerting but you can use Nagios for that although it might be overkill for you.

Our hosting provider offered up.time which provides monitoring/alerting and metrics on MySQL but I still went to the trouble of deploying Cacti because the up.time solution sucks compared to the Cacti templates.

Comment: The link is not coming up - I'll check it out tomorrow, but it sounds like it is not quite the all-in-one solution I am looking for...

Comment: up.time does have an all-in-one solution, but like I said: it sucks. Metric collection and alerting/monitoring are two different animals really. Any all-in-one solution is likely to not do both of these jobs well.

Comment: Actually, I believe a good alert / monitoring solution would have to perform metric collection in order to provide early warnings of issues before they become critical as well as provide valuable data for diagnosis.  But maybe there isn't such a system (except for possibly MySQL's Enterprise Monitor, which is out of our budget at $5K / server / year).

Answer (score 1):

there are several tools which are used to monitor mysql server. [Refer this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tools-for-monitor-admin-mysql-server.html).

I would recommend [mytop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-monitor-what-my-mysql-server-is-doing.html) and **phpmytop** incase you don't have access to ssh.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for more of an "all-in-one" tool, per my posting.

Answer (score 0):

We use [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) at work for monitoring queries etc. Really gives good insight into DB activity. You may also want to monitor your [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free tool to perform this on a lightweight budget and need on-the-fly metrics, go for MySQL Administrator. [**It's still free and still out there.**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4396/877) You can run it in Windows against a remote DBA server. I still use it today.

To install

- [**Open the ZIP File : Click Here**](http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-gui-tools-noinstall-5.0-r17-win32.zip/from/http://mirror.trouble-free.net/mysql_mirror/) (This is from the MySQL Developer Site)
- Create `C:\MySQLGUI`
- Open Windows Explorer on `C:\MySQLGUI`
- Double click 'MySQL GUI Tools 5.0' in the ZIP file
- Ctrl-A the whole List
- Copy and Paste List from ZIP File into Windows Explorer on `C:\MySQLGUI`
- Once copied in, double click 'MySQLAdministrator.exe' it should start right away

Comment: Found it, but it seems to have been replaced by MySQL Workbench.  Do you know if MySQL Workbench is good as well, or is the old version (MySQL Administrator) still better?

Comment: IMHO MySQLWorkbench is more convoluted